# How to open Textfile with c# ConsoleApplication and get Input as Parameter?

Tags: c#, path, console, arguments

I want to write an own little c# application which takes the input of an textfile as argument(s). So, I write a Textfile which input is "-login User" with and save it with an unkown file extension. I try to open it with my Console Application -> and get the following error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

If I open my application via cmd with:  "test.exe  test1 test2" it works and Test1 and Test2 are taken as Parameters.

I wrote this in Code to get my Parameters:

string arg1 = args[0];
string arg2 = args[1];

Why does this not work, maybe some one can help me with this. 
Additionally, if its possible to open my Textfile and i can get the Arguments - is it possible to get the full path of the Textfile the Program was opened with?

Comment: ok so are you providing the arguments in the debug parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that if you run your application in Visual Studio you get the IndexOutOfRangeException but from cmd it works?

Then you just have to add the arguments in your project debug settings. Right click your project, go to Properties, open Debug and put your arguments in the Command line arguments text field.

[image]

> is it possible to get the full path of the Textfile the Program was opened with?

I'm not 100% sure what you mean but I think you want to use [Path.GetFullPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfullpath?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: No, if i open an text file where "Test1 and Test2" is in with the application i get the error. The debug mode like shown from you works :)